# maven 3.2.3 fails to import resources correctly

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a project that uses maven profiles to set a properties file so I can use different properties for different environments.

With maven version 3.2.1 (default version bundled with Eclipse Luna) this all works swimmingly. However, I downloaded the latest version of maven, 3.2.3, and when I set that as my maven version, it all blows up. The values are read as empty strings.

Should I submit a Maven bug for this? I couldn't find anything in the release notes for [3.2.2](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.2/release-notes.html) or [3.2.3](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/release-notes.html) that looked like it should've caused this.

Here's the profile:

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/config/local</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Then I use Spring to add the file to the classpath:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {

    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    props.setLocations(new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("service.properties") });
    return props;
}
```

And eventually import its values:

```
@Value(value = "${db.username}")
private String DB_USERNAME;
```

Comment: I encountered some simliar problems, when upgrading. For me it was resolved by not only declearing the `directory`, but as well providing an excplicit `<includes><include> myFile.properties</include></includes>`. It *seems* like everything that is not *explicitly included* is *implicitly excluded*.

Comment: That appears to have fixed my issue. You should probably make it an answer! Seems like the kind of info that ought to be in the release notes, and I'm also not sure why they would do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered some simliar problems, when upgrading. For me it was resolved by not only declearing the directory, but as well providing an excplicit

```
<includes>
   <include>myFile.properties</include>
</includes>
```

It seems like everything that is not *explicitly included* is *implicitly excluded*.

I dunno if this is a bug or a feature :)

Comment: I raised a bug report for this: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5704 - lets see if it is intended, unknown - or if we just ever did it wrong :)